# How to parse string with special characters from database using php?

Tags: java, php, mysql, xml, special-characters

I had a MySQL database with names of roads in it. There is this one entry that gives me problems when I query it from the database: **Osmeña Avenue**. I stored the data to the DB using Java, and then I viewed the data using phpMyadmin then I saw **4f736d65c3b161204176656e7565** instead of **Osmeña Avenue**. When I query for the names, I placed them inside an XML file, which I use for my application. When I query for **Osmeña Avenue**, my program freezes. I found out that in the XML file, the **ñ** is replaced by a �, which causes the freeze. First, why do I saw a bunch of numbers in the phpMyAdmin view for **Osmeña Avenue**? And what can I do to get the right string with the special characters from the database using PHP? Thanks in advance!

EDIT:
the XML file is used to draw routes using OpenLayers.Format.KML;.

Comment: What encoding type use for your DB?

Comment: have made sure that you are using UTF-8 instead of ASCII to encode your characters?

Comment: Please check this entry in DB and if there you have � chars, use UTF-8

Comment: I did. In phpMyAdmin, Osmeña Avenue is 4f736d65c3b161204176656e7565. I did use utf8_bin.

Comment: How do you generate XML? When you generate it you must use same encoding.

Comment: @Faraona. When I build the XML file, I always include <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

Comment: But when you get data from MySql do you set your query encoding type to UTF8?

Comment: $Faraona +1 for the hint. I didn't know that I can set that using **mysql_set_charset('utf8')**. So then when I insert data to the database, I need to insert them using the UTF-8 encoding, so that I will not see the bunch of numbers?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`4f736d65c3b161204176656e7565` is a sequence of bytes (`4f`, `73`,..) that represent `Osme\xc3\xb1a Avenue`, which is the UTF-8 representation of `Osmeña Avenue`.

Just decode your data properly. Inside your app, keep working only with Unicode strings, and encode/decode string data at system edges.

Comment: can you tell me how I'll do it? Should I use decode when I extract the data from the database or when I build the XML file?

Comment: data in your database is encoded as UTF-8. as you read it (from a select statement presumably), you decode it and store decoded (in data objects or otherwise). this way you never care about encodings while processing your data, until you need t actually output it, e.g. to an XML file. XML serializers are usually smart enough to do encoding for you, but if you create your files 'by hand', that' s where you decode it — preferably to UTF-8, though Latin-1 may do in this case, too. Also, take 30 mins off coding duties and read [Spolsky's intro](http://www.joelonsoftware.com/articles/Unicode.html).

Answer (score -2):

Don't use `utf8_bin`, use `utf8_general` instead.

Or, it would be even better to just use `latin1_swedish_ci` or `latin1_swedish_cs`.

Comment: Why? How would another collation (in the case of using _general) help here? And to the second part - what about internationalization? If you expect every character in your app to be 1-byte, you'll have problems trying to internationalize it later. UTF-8 is generally a good choice.